Solutions to fix Forward Vector Flips in a Spline Circle
I’m trying to create a spline circle, and I have spline meshes attached to it. I noticed spline point 2 and 3 (the last two before closing the loop) have flipped forward vectors, which causes my spline meshes to flip also. It's not clear to me why the flips happen, and how to flip them back again.
This is the code I’m using:
{
    if (!SplineComponent) return;
    SplineComponent->ClearSplinePoints(false);

    // Add spline points in a circle, constrained to Y and Z axes
    const int32 NumberOfPoints = 4;
    for (int32 i = 0; i < NumberOfPoints; ++i)
    {
        float Angle = (i / static_cast<float>(NumberOfPoints)) * 2.0f * PI;
        float Y = SplineRadius * FMath::Cos(Angle);
        float Z = SplineRadius * FMath::Sin(Angle);
        float X = 0.0f;  // X remains constant in my use case

        FVector Position(X, Y, Z);
        FVector Tangent = FVector(0.0f, -SplineRadius * FMath::Sin(Angle), SplineRadius * FMath::Cos(Angle));
        SplineComponent->AddSplinePoint(Position, ESplineCoordinateSpace::Local, false);
        SplineComponent->SetTangentAtSplinePoint(i, Tangent, ESplineCoordinateSpace::Local, false);
    }
    SplineComponent->UpdateSpline();
}

Anybody have some ideas how I can fix the forward vector flips?
What I tried is changing the up vector upon creation of the spline meshes, but it looked like it had no effect (perhaps UpdateSpline() re-flips them ...) and I also tried "forcing" a rotation in the code, but it usually ends up rotating the entire spline, rather than the meshes.
